# How to use below syntax in chart.js 3.x?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

How to use below syntax in chart.js version 3?

```
 Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
           Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
           draw: function(ease) {
              Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Chart.js provides verry good documentation, ease take a look at it first because big chance your answer will be in there: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types

Comment: 'Read the documentation' is not really an answer to his question. The provided URL is not relevant either.

Comment: Read documentation is a perfectly fine answer to this question since he showed 0 effort of even trying to do it himself, also link is relevant since it even has an example on how to achieve what he wants